# Usage of Columns in dash bootstrap components example

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

The (for instance) "**horizontal form**" code example of the `Form` component of the dash bootstrap components documentation (https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/form/) looks like this:

```
# ...
email_input = dbc.Row(
    [
        dbc.Label("Email", html_for="example-email-row", width=2),
        dbc.Col(
            dbc.Input(
                type="email", id="example-email-row", placeholder="Enter email"
            ),
            width=10,
        ),
    ],
    className="mb-3",
)
# ...
```

Why is the `Input` component in a `Col`, but the `Label` is not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From dbc docs:

> Create a horizontal form by using the Row component. Be sure to
> specify width on the Label component, and wrap your inputs in Col
> components.

`Label` act as "col-type" element when `width` parameter is specified. So when `width=2`, width of the label will be two columns and rest of them (10) will be filled by `dbc.Col()` (in your example you have `width=10` but you can omit this parameter).

See the example from Bootstrap docs, uses similar approach (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/form-control/#readonly-plain-text). Label has `col-sm-2 col-form-label` classes.

Comment: So, essentially, I could also write `dbc.Col(dbc.Label("Email", html_for="example-email-row"), width=2)`?

Comment: @LCsa I do not think so, you would end up with col inside col (you do not want that), bootstrap is designed in this way to prevent putting anything else into form label i guess.